# Getting array subscript of a C program using cdt eclipse

Tags: java, c, arrays, windows, eclipse-cdt

Iam trying to implement the buffer overrun problem of a C program using java with the help of  eclipse CDT . 
By giving a constant value as the array subscript, its working fine as I expected.

See the sample code:

```
   CASTArraySubscriptExpression exprsn =     (CASTArraySubscriptExpression)astName.getParent().getParent();

    String size = exprsn.getSubscriptExpression().toString();
    System.out.println("Size : " + size);
```

Using this code, able to detect the array subscript value of the below code:

```
int a[10];
a[12] = 4;//Here it detect the buffer overrun problem.
```

But if I give like this:

```
int a[10];
int i = 21;
a[i] = 4;
```

Here, not able to detect the value of the index `i`. 
How I can detect the value using CDT?

Comment: Does it work if you mark it `const int i = 21;`?

Comment: No,I got the same result as org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.c.CASTIdExpression@516ba9

Answer (score 1):

In the second case it is not enough to just look at the AST of a subscript expression to detect an error, you need at least some basic [data flow analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis).

However, according to [CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis) building a data flow graph is planned as future work, so you either have to do it yourself or wait until it is implemented.

As a simple solution for the special case like your second example, when you have a local variable reference in the subscript, you can check if the variable is not used anywhere in the AST between the initialization and its use in subscript.